# 8 bit PICs: timer1 asynchronous vs synchronous operation

Tags: microcontroller, pic, timer, synchronous

The 8-bit PIC family (I'm working with pic18f46k22) offers some timers (timers1/3/5) that can work in both asynchronous and synchronous modes when clocked from an external source.

The obvious differences are:

1. asynchronous operation gives the possibility for timer to run in sleep mode
2. An asynchronous source can clock the timer faster since it is independent on the system clock (table 27-12):
   [image: timing specifications]

and as for the advantages for synchronizing the external clock source... well, I can't see any. One disadvantage to think of is the possible corruption of data if the CPU tries to read the counter while it is incrementing, but the datasheet states:

> 12.5.1 READING AND WRITING TIMER1/3/5 IN ASYNCHRONOUS COUNTER MODE:
>   Reading TMRxH or TMRxL while the timer is running from an external asynchronous clock will ensure a valid read (taken care of in hardware).

Can someone please explain why did they add the possibility to synchronize the external clock source with the internal phase clocks? I feel that I'm missing something.
Thanx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some operations on the timer don't work when it might change in the middle of a cycle.  This timer is used in conjunction with CCP modules too.  Read the datasheet section on the CCP modules and you will probably find restrictions of when it must be run in synchronous mode.

For example, compare to a particular value can be flaky if the timer value might change in the middle of the compare operation, or might increment past the compare point between checks.

Comment: That may explains a lot:
14.1.2 TIMER1 MODE RESOURCE
The 16-bit Timer resource must be running in Timer
mode or Synchronized Counter mode for the CCP
module to use the capture feature. In Asynchronous
Counter mode, the capture operation may not work.
This is probably one reason for adding the synchronization option

Answer (score 1):

If you need a timer to operate in sleep mode, it must be set in asynchronous mode, and if the timer is set in asynchronous mode any change to change its state under processor control (including switching between synchronous and asynchronous mode) which occurs at the same time as an incoming pulse may cause its state to be corrupted in arbitrary fashion.

If you have two async-capable timers, I would suggest that you configure one of them to run continuously and never do anything with it except read its value.  Such reads should be performed by reading the low byte, then the
high byte, and then the low byte again.  If the low byte changed between
the two reads, repeat the process.  The other timer may be configured for
wake-up events, but with a few caveats:

1. Write the low byte of the timer before doing anything else to change it and read it afterward.  If the low byte has changed, assume that the timer might have been arbitrarily corrupted and start again from scratch.
2. On at lest some parts, the timer interrupt occurs on the clock edge after a clock edge that advances the timer from 0xFFFE to 0xFFFF.  Programming the timer with a value of 0xFFFF will not cause an interrupt on the first tick following such action, but rather on the 65,537th tick.  I don't know if there's a way to set the timer to get an interrupt on the next tick.

Using these techniques together, it's possible to logically combine the two async-capable timers to yield the functionality that would be available on a timer with an asynchronous-compare facility.

Comment: Hi, I was waiting for you to answer as I read your post on a similar issue... I actually have no design issue and I was only setting the timer to work as an edge counter. But I kinda hanged on the synchronization option... My question was that I can't figure why is there an option to synchronize the external clock source if the asynchronous operation is obviously more advantageous

Comment: the microcontroller also has the feature to buffer the high byte when reading the low byte and I can't figure out why shouldn't I use this mode. It should solve the issue you pointed to and always return a good read. the same is correct for writes as the buffered value of the high byte is written when the low byte is written to and hence guarantee a good write

Comment: @fhlb: If the timer is in asynchronous mode, one must read the lower byte twice even if one doesn't care about the upper byte, and would have to read the upper byte twice if one never looked at the lower byte.  If one reads a byte at the exact moment it changes from 0x7F to 0x80, or from 0xFF to 0x00, it could report any value, and the upper-byte latch does nothing to avoid that issue.  If two reads yield the same value and it's not possible that the counter has incremented a multiple of 256 times between the reads, the value is guaranteed correct, but two reads are definitely required.

Comment: I understand that reading an asynchronous counter may pose the risks you pointed to, but the datasheet clearly states that a valid read is always insured, and that the problem is when the timer overflows between the read of the lower byte and the read of the higher byte. I'm not that clocked electronics guru and I can't tell how is that possible but shouldn't we trust the datasheet?

Comment: 12.5.1 READING AND WRITING TIMER1/3/5 IN ASYNCHRONOUS COUNTER MODE:
Reading TMRxH or TMRxL while the timer is running from an external asynchronous clock will ensure a valid read (taken care of in hardware). However, the user should keep in mind that reading the 16-bit timer in two 8-bit values itself, poses certain problems, since the timer may overflow between the reads.

Comment: @fhlb: There are a number of ways a CPU maker might try to make such reads reliable.  Many of them will reduce the probability of failure but not eliminate it.  Given the errata I've had to deal with over the years, I don't trust Microchip to have actually implemented such measures correctly, especially given that doing so requires a lot of extra circuitry.  Also, code which uses the high-byte buffer technique may have problems if there are any interrupts that might need to read the timer state, since that's may a problematic sequence of events:

Comment: 1. Mainline code reads low byte value of FF and captures high byte; 2. Counter increments 3. Interrupt reads low byte and captures high byte; 3. Mainline code reads what it expects to be the buffered high byte.  If an interrupt could occur and read the timer after the mainline code has read the low byte, the main-line code has to guard against that; guarding against that possibility by reading the timer low byte twice in the main-line code is just as easy as using any other means, so I don't see any reason not to use that approach in which case it won't matter whether reads are 100% reliable.

Comment: Incidentally, determining whether some event occurred before a particular clock cycle is a fundamentally hard problem, and there's no hard limit on how long such a determination can take.  The best one can do is decide, on the next cycle, whether the system had yet decided that the event took place; the logic to detect the original invent might take more than a cycle to decide that an event which occurred almost precisely at a clock cycle boundary actually occurred before the clock, but it's unlikely to reach that conclusion at the precise moment the next clock arrives.

Comment: Your multi-byte timer read procedure is backwards.  You read the high byte, low byte, then high byte again, and keep the first two if the second high byte matches the first.  If not, do it again.  It doesn't matter if the low byte changes between reads, only that there be no carry from the low to high byte between reads.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: I am disinclined trust the result of a single read of a multi-bit quantity from an asynchronous domain unless I know something of the synchronization mechanisms used.  Reading low-high-low will work even if one of the reads yields a bogus value because the low byte was incrementing from 0x7F to 0x80.  Reading high-low-high would fail in that case.

Comment: @supe: No, it wouldn't fail.  Think of each of the possible cases where a increment and carry can happen.  High-inc-low-high yeilds the incremented value.  High-low-inc-high yield the unincremented value. High-carry-low-high is a do over.  So is high-low-carry-high.  Show me a case where it doesn't work.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Incoming timer-clock pulse arrives precisely at the threshold of being reportable via the current read, such that the latching circuit which is supposed to indicate whether that clock pulse should affect the current read goes metastable, causing some bits to report the new clock value and others to report the old clock value.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Maybe Microchip managed to properly implement one of the hardware-only solutions to avoid such corruption, but they require a fair bit of silicon which isn't necessary if code uses the approach I describe.  Note that there are some cheap measures which make a "split" read less likely than it would be if no measures were applied to reduce that risk, but the cheap members still have a non-trivial failure probability.

Answer (score 1):

supercat mentioned reading microchip erratas... look at the PIC18(L)F26/46K22 Rev. A2/A4 Silicon Errata and Data Sheet Clarification(this microcontroller you're using):

> 5. Module: Timer1/3/5
>
> When Timer1, Timer3 or Timer5 is operated in Asynchronous External Input mode, unexpected interrupt flag generation may occur if an external clock edge arrives too soon following a firmware write to the TMRxH:TMRxL registers. An unexpected interrupt flag event may also occur when enabling the module or switching from Synchronous to Asynchronous mode.
>
> Work around:
>
> This issue only applies when operating the timer in Asynchronous mode. Whenever possible, operate the timer module in Synchronous mode to avoid spurious timer interrupts.

A quick search on google also shows other issues with the asynchronous timer mode with other microcontrollers (example: pic18f4550 errata- fail of the buffered read mechanism and the pic18f97j60 family errata)
so its probably a good point not to trust the asynchronous timer too much and add the extra two line of code to verify any read/write. and don't forget the sample code provided in the errata to clear the unexpected interrupt flag generation upon a timer write

Comment: Just found this:
http://www.microchip.com//wwwAppNotes/AppNotes.aspx?appnote=en573101